# Is there a way to skip every command line that throws an error in R without `tryCatch`ing every single line?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have a script for some data analysis in R which is a wrapper around many operations. Some of them depend on a previous operation, some not. Is there a way to simply continue the script if some operation fails?
I know about `tryCatch` but I don't want to wrap every single little command in a `tryCatch` block. I would rather have some way of simply ignoring every error and go on with the script.

Update to explain my situation more clearly: I have a group of data sets, one for each sample in my experiment. My code currently takes one data set, executes some operations (e.g. normalizing, excluding parts that doesn't interest me etc.), fit different models (essentially regressions and log regressions) and plot.
I loop this code for each of my samples. I know that, for a particular sample, not all operations will work (specially if the data set is missing important data), but some of them will always work (like the plots of the 'vanilla' data, before any operations).
What I want is to ignore errors when running this script, skipping to the next line every time one operation does not work, since I still want some of the output even for the 'bad' data sets (like the 'vanilla' plots mentioned above).
I understand I can do this by wrapping each operation in a `tryCatch` function, but I was hoping for a simpler (and maybe sloppier) way of doing this.

Comment: If a part does not depend on a previous result, then why is it included so as to introduce an error?

Comment: @kristang perhaps the line runs a model and throws an error because the data are not suited for this particular model. User wants to ignore such cases. mparada, see `?options` if under `error` you read anything useful. I personally would go the extra step and implement `tryCatch` for every "line", changing global settings is... eh. :)

Comment: My point was more that it seems like a bad setup, and I am having trouble visualizing how you might end up in such a situation.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I checked the `options(error)` but could only find two possibilities: `recover` and `dump.frames`. In both I enter an interactive mode, but I want to automatically skip to next step. I tried creating my own empty function (`skipError() <- function(){}`) and assigned it to the `error` parameter in `options` ('options(error = skipError)`) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try()`

```
try(log("a"),silent = T)
```

Comment: I read the docs for `try` and I can't see how is it different from `tryCatch` for my case. I still would have to wrap every single command in a `try` function...

Comment: @mparada with try you dont need to catch the errors and warnings. It just passes the line if get error.

Comment: @vck yes, you are right. I don't need to catch the errors. But that is not my issue. I would still have to wrap each line in a `try`. I was hoping for a way of globally skipping errors and continuing with a function.